# How to create view via fragment that is linked to applicatio model eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, e4

Using application.e4xmi, I want to create view via fragments using this application model. Could you please tell me the step by step procedure.

what i have tried is, i have created one fragment in the one plugin application. in that i have given application id after that i have created part stack and after that created part. Here i have given class URI is my view class(path of view class in the viewplugin project). But without that view plugin in the runconfigurations, i am unable to see view part.

Comment: What do you mean by 'with that view plugin in the run configurations'? You must have all your plugins in the run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you wish to have a plugin containing a model fragment which contributes to an application model located in another plugin, and the problem is that a *(View-)Part* you tried to contribute that way doesn't show in the application window. I hope I didn't get you wrong there and I will assume that the error is not just that the plugin with the model fragment is not included in the run configurations... (?)

You can find a useful tutorial in [Lars Vogel's webpages](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Modularity/article.html#contributefragment). However, as the various requirements may be confusing, I will summarize the process for potential future readers.

**TL;DR**:

- You might have set a wrong *Element ID* and/or *Featurename* for your *Part*.
- Your question implies that you maybe tried to implement a *Part* model element as a *ViewPart*, when in E4, there is no longer any interface for a (View) Part to implement, so maybe try creating the Part controls in a `@PostConstruct`-annotated method instead.
- Another possible reason for your contributed *Part* not showing up is the plugin providing the model fragment not having the correct settings for the bundle options `SymbolicName` and/or `ActivationPolicy` (*'Plug-in is singleton'* and *'Activate when class is loaded'*).

### Application

In order to have an application model to contribute to, we first need an Eclipse4 application project. Create one by selecting *File -> New -> Other* from the Eclipse main menu. Choose the wizard *Eclipse 4 Application Project* in the *Eclipse 4* category. Name your project as you wish, choose Equinox as OSGI framework, and check the *Generate an Activator...* option. The newly created project will contain a file `Application.e4xmi`  (your application model) and a `*.product` file (product definition). Open the latter in and make sure `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application` is set as *Application* in the *Overview* tab.

Open `Application.e4xmi` and append a *Part Stack* somewhere in the model tree, as you probably have already done anyways.

### Model fragment

Create a new plugin for the model fragment. Letting it have an `Activator` class won't harm. It is important, however, that the options *Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded* and *This plug-in is a singleton* **are both checked** in the *Overview* tab of its `plugin.xml` editor. Next, create a model fragment with *New -> Other... -> Eclipse 4 -> Model -> New Model Fragment* in the plugin's Package Explorer context menu. The wizard will automatically create an extension of `org.bbaw.bts.ui.pdr.fragment` specifying your model fragment file. The plugin's dependencies should include:

```
org.eclipse.swt
org.eclipse.jface
org.eclipse.e4.core.di
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
javax.inject
org.eclipse.e4.ui.di
```

Open the model fragment file (`fragment.e4xmi` by default) and attach a *Model Fragment* to the *Model Fragments* node. Your new *Model Fragment* element needs to specify both an *Element ID* and a *Featurename* in order to correctly address the *Application Model*'s element that you want to contribute to. Thus, copy the ***ID* of the *Part Stack*** previously created in the *Application Model* into the ***Element ID* field** of the *Model Fragment* you've just created. In the *Featurename* field, type `children`, as this is the Part stack's attribute we want to contribute to. Then, append a *Part* to the *Model Fragment* element and specify the *Class URI* of the Part's implementation. This class is basically a POJO, no implementation of `ViewPart` is necessary! It creates its GUI in a method annotated with the `@PostConstruct` annotation, e.g.

```
@PostConstruct
public final void createComposite(final Composite parent)
```

That should be it. When running the application project's product, the Part should appear like expected (given the plugin containing that Part is included in the run configuration...).